# Update multiple nested elements conditionally mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection of documents that looks like this:

```
[
  {"_id":ObjectId('602a7a9ac0bf9d23c67a41ba'),
    'brand':'horn',
    'products':[
      {'type':'red','ticks':0,'name':'model 1'},
      {'type':'green','ticks':0,'name':'model 2'},
      {'type':'red','ticks':0,'name':'model 3'},
    ]
  },
  {"_id":ObjectId('602a7a9ac0bf9d23c67a1234'),
    'brand':'leg',
    'products':[
      {'type':'red','ticks':0,'name':'model 1'},
    ]
  },
]
```

I would like to update all documents with the `brand:horn` and increment all products with not the `type:red` by 1. I am currently querying this way:

```
coll.updateMany({ "brand": "horn", "products.type": { $ne: "red" } }, { $inc: { "products.$.ticks": 1 } }, { 'multi': true })
```

However this is not working. How can I perform this update properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the part for the array filter `"products.type": { $ne: "red" }` in the wrong place.
It should be written in option `arrayFilters`.

Your update should look like this:

```
coll.updateMany({ "brand": "horn"}, { $inc: { "products.$[element].ticks": 1 } }, { 'multi': true,  arrayFilters: [{"element.type": { $ne: "red" }}]});
```

In addition to the answer your query:
`{ "brand": "horn", "products.type": { $ne: "red" } }`
Will return empty result, since your document with `brand=horn` has at least one product where `type=red`

Comment: Would it be possible to write an update where it would update the second object `{'type':'green','ticks':0,'name':'model 2'},` in the `brand=horn` and `type=red`?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what exactly do you mean. The 2nd object has `type=green`

Comment: Yes so as it is not red `$ne: "red"` is there no way to update it?

Comment: If you live `products.type": { $ne: "red" }` in your main query, as it is in your question it will not update, since the query will not return any documents. But if you change your query a bit into: `{"brand": "horn", "products": { $elemMatch: { "type": { $ne: "red" }}}}` then it will, but you still have to apply `arrayFilter`